# Is there anyway to import a csv file that contains multiple worksheets using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

The load data infile only imports the first sheet.

> "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\\user\\Desktop\\example.csv'
>           INTO TABLE `exampletable` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
>           IGNORE 1 LINES (`Id`, `Name`)";

Is it possible to upload the 2nd sheet simultaneously with the first sheet?

Answer (score 0):

When you export a worksheet in an Excel workbook to CSV, you usually do so one sheet at a time.  So, to do what you want you might have to open the first CSV file and append the second one at the end.  This assumes that both sheets would have the same number and types of columns.  You also might have to remove the header row from the second CSV file before combining it.

It should be possible to write a VBA script to iterate all sheets and generate a single CSV output.  But that would be a bit of work, and perhaps not worth it for you to do.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

But are there any ways for us to upload a whole workbook?

Comment: That's not a particularly well-defined question, because in general two different worksheets could have data having nothing in common with each other.  A database table is much more structured than an Excel worksheet, and, in general, you would need to load a CSV file which has not only the same number of columns, but also the same type of data.  We could write a VBA script to generate a single CSV file, but it would have many assumptions, and you would also have to know enough to use it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try researching more in the VBA script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an exact answer to your question using VBA.  For where you are right now, just combining the CSV files manually would probably be faster.